# How to wait for the response when is finished in interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, interceptor

I have interceptor.I want to show loading spinner,so everywhere where i am having subscribe methods to wait for the subscribtion to be finished ,show the loading spinner in that time and when it is finished to hide that loading spinner.

If i do that in each component it is easy and it is working.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.spinnerService.show();
    this.service.methodName().subscribe(data => {
    },error => {
    },() => {
        this.spinnerService.hide();
    })
}
```

But how can i do that in this interceptor? With this code the spinner is showed very short time when the request is made ONLY and then disapperas.I have requests that take longer time...

```
 if (request.url.includes(this.apiUrl)) {
    this.spinnerService.show();
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    cloneRequest = request.clone({ headers: headers });
} else {
    cloneRequest = request.clone();
}
return next.handle(cloneRequest).pipe(map(response => {
            this.spinnerService.hide();
            return response;
        })).pipe(catchError(error => {
            let errorMessage = 'An unexpected error occured';
            if (error.error && error.error.message) {
                errorMessage = error.error.message;
            }
            // TODO: Error notifications are currently disabled.
            if (request.url.includes('login')) {
                this.notificationService.showError(errorMessage);
            }
            return throwError(error)
        }));
```

Comment: You have a good exemple here if it can help : https://firstclassjs.com/display-a-loader-on-every-http-request-using-interceptor-in-angular-7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple API requests, so when the first one is finished, it hides the spinner, even though the 2nd one is not done yet. You can use a counter on your `spinnerService`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpinnerService {
  get shouldShow(): boolean {
    return !!this.count;
  }

  private count: number = 0; 

  show(): void {
    this.count++;
  }

  hide(): void {
    this.count = Math.max(0, this.count - 1);
  }
}
```

You have to update your interceptor though to handle this, because api calls which do not show the spinner will now decrease the spinner count. To adjust for this you should check if it should decrease. Also the `finalize` pipe of rxjs is a perfect place to put such a thing:

```
const showSpinner = request.url.includes(this.apiUrl);

if (showSpinner) {
  this.spinnerService.show();

  cloneRequest = request.clone({ headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  }) });
} else {
  cloneRequest = request.clone();
}

return next.handle(cloneRequest).pipe(
  catchError(error => //...),
  finalize(() => {
    if (showSpinner) {
      this.spinnerService.hide();
    }
  })
);
```

---

A wrapper service for `Ng4LoadingSpinnerService` can look as simple as this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpinnerService {
  private count: number = 0; 

  constructor(private ss: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService) {}

  show(): void {
    if (!this.count) {
      this.ss.show();
    }

    this.count++;
  }

  hide(): void {
    this.count = Math.max(0, this.count - 1);

    if (!this.count) {
      this.ss.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But i can't make tha counters , the project that i got at work already use Ng4LoadingSpinnerService... :( this.spinnerService.show is already implemented to show the spinner  i cant make it only on some codition

Comment: @Trajce12 there is no other way around it. You need to use counters. Best would be to make a wrapper service which controls the `Ng4LoadingSpinnerService`

Comment: @Trajce12 I've updated my answer with a wrapper example

Comment: Thank you Poul.I tried that too,but it is not working :(

Comment: @Trajce12 I've updated my answer, I made a mistake with the count setting